# Excel + npgsql + postgres. Specified cast is not valid exception

Tags: excel, postgresql, npgsql

I'm trying to connect my MS Excel 2013 Pro+ with PostgreSQL DB using Power Query and Npgsql connector.

Everything seems to be fine, until - I'll try to run custom query (eg. select * from table). Then - there's an error message coming up: "The specified cas is not valid". If I'll use the DB structure browser - I'm able to select table or view and hit 'Load' but it's also giving me same error.

Is there something I do wrong, or is there some bug in the connector?

Here's the stacktrace from Excel:

```
Feedback Type:
```

Frown (Error)

Timestamp:
2017-08-21T09:14:00.7435203Z

Local Time:
2017-08-21T11:14:00.7435203+02:00

Product Version:
2.48.4792.941 (PQ-CY17SU07) (x86)

Release:
July, 2017

Excel Version:
15.0.4420.1017

Excel Install Location:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15\EXCEL.EXE

IE Version:
11.0.9600.17843

OS Version:
Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 (x86 pl-PL)

CLR Version:
4.6.1 or later [Release Number = 394271]

Workbook Package Info:
1* - en-US, Query Groups: 0, fastCombine: Disabled, runBackgroundAnalysis: True.

Peak Working Set:
268 MB

Private Memory:
231 MB

Peak Virtual Memory:
930 MB

Error Message:
Specified cast is not valid.

Stack Trace:
Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.Interface.ErrorException: Specified cast is not valid. ---> Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.Interface.ErrorException: Specified cast is not valid. ---> Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.Interface.ErrorException: Specified cast is not valid. ---> System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid. ---> System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
   at Microsoft.OleDb.Serialization.PageWriter.WriteSchema(DataTable schemaTable)
   at Microsoft.OleDb.Serialization.OleDbPageWriter..ctor(Stream stream, DataTable schemaTable)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.RemotePageReader.<>c__DisplayClass7.b__0()
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.EvaluationHost.ReportExceptions(IHostTrace trace, IEngineHost engineHost, IMessageChannel channel, Action action)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.EvaluationHost.<>c__DisplayClass7.b__6()
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Common.SafeExceptions.IgnoreSafeExceptions(IEngineHost host, IHostTrace trace, Action action)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.EvaluationHost.TryReportException(IHostTrace trace, IEngineHost engineHost, IMessageChannel channel, Exception exception)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.EvaluationHost.ReportExceptions(IHostTrace trace, IEngineHost engineHost, IMessageChannel channel, Action action)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.RemotePageReader.RunStub(IEngineHost engineHost, IMessageChannel channel, Func`1 getPageReader)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.RemoteDocumentEvaluator.Service.<>c__DisplayClass11.<OnBeginGetDataReaderSource>b__f(EvaluationResult2`1 result)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.RemoteDocumentEvaluator.Service.<>c__DisplayClass1e`1.<OnBeginGetResult>b__1b()
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.EvaluationHost.ReportExceptions(IHostTrace trace, IEngineHost engineHost, IMessageChannel channel, Action action)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.RemoteDocumentEvaluator.Service.OnBeginGetResult[T](IMessageChannel channel, BeginGetResultMessage message, Action`1 action)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.RemoteDocumentEvaluator.Service.OnBeginGetDataReaderSource(IMessageChannel channel, BeginGetDataReaderSourceMessage message)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.MessageHandlers.<>c__DisplayClassa`1.<AddHandler>b__8(IMessageChannel channel, Message message)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.MessageHandlers.TryDispatch(IMessageChannel channel, Message message)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.ChannelMessenger.ChannelMessageHandlers.TryDispatch(IMessageChannel channel, Message message)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.MessageHandlers.Dispatch(IMessageChannel channel, Message message)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.ChannelMessenger.OnMessageWithUnknownChannel(IMessageChannel baseChannel, MessageWithUnknownChannel messageWithUnknownChannel)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.MessageHandlers.<>c__DisplayClassa`1.b__8(IMessageChannel channel, Message message)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.MessageHandlers.TryDispatch(IMessageChannel channel, Message message)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.ChannelMessenger.ChannelMessageHandlers.TryDispatch(IMessageChannel channel, Message message)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.MessageHandlers.Dispatch(IMessageChannel channel, Message message)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.EvaluationHost.Run()
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Container.EvaluationContainerMain.Run(Object args)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.SafeThread2.<>c__DisplayClass2.b__0(Object o)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.SafeThread2.<>c__DisplayClass15.b__14(Object o)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.SafeThread2.<>c__DisplayClass2.b__1(Object o)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Container.EvaluationContainerMain.SafeRun(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Container.EvaluationContainerMain.Main(String[] args)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.EvaluationHost.OnException(IEngineHost engineHost, IMessageChannel channel, ExceptionMessage message)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.RemoteEvaluationContainerFactory.Container.OnException(IMessageChannel channel, ExceptionMessage message)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.MessageHandlers.<>c__DisplayClassa`1.<AddHandler>b__8(IMessageChannel channel, Message message)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.MessageHandlers.TryDispatch(IMessageChannel channel, Message message)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.MessageHandlers.Dispatch(IMessageChannel channel, Message message)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.ChannelMessenger.ChannelMessageHandlers.TryDispatch(IMessageChannel channel, Message message)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.MessageHandlers.Dispatch(IMessageChannel channel, Message message)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.Interface.IMessageChannelExtensions.WaitFor[T](IMessageChannel channel)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.MessageBasedInputStream.ReadNextChunkAndCheckIfClosed()
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.MessageBasedInputStream.ReadNextChunk()
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.ChunkedInputStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.IO.BinaryReader.FillBuffer(Int32 numBytes)
   at System.IO.BinaryReader.ReadInt32()
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.ITableSourceSerializationExtensions.ReadITableSource(BinaryReader reader)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.RemotePageReader.CreateProxy(IEngineHost engineHost, IMessageChannel channel, ExceptionHandler exceptionHandler)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.RemoteDocumentEvaluator.DataReaderSourceRemoteEvaluation.GetResult(Boolean enableFirewall)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.RemoteDocumentEvaluator.RemoteEvaluation.Evaluate(Boolean enableFirewall)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.RemoteDocumentEvaluator.RemoteEvaluation`1.TryCompleteWithException(Exception exception)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.RemoteDocumentEvaluator.RemoteEvaluation.Evaluate(Boolean enableFirewall)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.RemoteDocumentEvaluator.EvaluationThread(Object state)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.GlobalizedEvaluatorThreadPool.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__3(Object s)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.EvaluatorThreadPool.EvaluatorThread(Object state)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.SafeThread2.<>c__DisplayClass2.b__0(Object o)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.SafeThread2.<>c__DisplayClass15.b__14(Object o)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.SafeThread2.<>c__DisplayClass2.b__1(Object o)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart(Object obj)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Server stack trace:

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at Microsoft.OleDb.AsyncResult`1.get_Value()
   at Microsoft.Mashup.OleDbProvider.DataHost.BufferingMashupEvaluator.BufferingMashupEvaluation.GetBufferedReaderSource(AsyncResult`1 result)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.OleDbProvider.DataHost.BufferingMashupEvaluator.BufferingMashupEvaluation.OnEvaluationComplete(AsyncResult`1 result)

Exception rethrown at [1]: 
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Host.ProviderShared.MashupResource.GetStatus()
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.Fill.PollingFillDownloadWorker.b__1()
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.Fill.PollingFillDownloadWorker.InvokeWorker(Func`1 action)

Invocation Stack Trace:
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.ExceptionExtensions.GetCurrentInvocationStackTrace()
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.ClientShared.StackTraceInfo..ctor(String exceptionStackTrace, String invocationStackTrace)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.ClientShared.FeedbackErrorInfo..ctor(String message, Nullable`1 errorCode, String requestId, Exception exception)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.ClientShared.UnexpectedExceptionHandler.<>c__DisplayClass1.<HandleException>b__0()
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.SynchronizationContextExtensions.SendAndMarshalExceptions(SynchronizationContext context, Action callback)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.ClientShared.UnexpectedExceptionHandler.HandleException(Exception e)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.Fill.FillSession.HandleDownloaderException(IWorkbook workbook, Exception e)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.Fill.PollingInitialFillSession.FillDownloadResult(IWorkbook workbook, Boolean onTimer)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.Fill.PollingInitialFillSession.<>c__DisplayClass4.<ResumeFill>b__0()
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.Fill.IUndoServicesExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass2.<InvokeWithConditionalDiscardedUndoScope>b__0(IUndoScope undoScope)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.Shim.AddInUndoServices.InvokeUndoableAction(IWorkbook workbook, UndoableActionType actionType, Action`1 action)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.Fill.IUndoServicesExtensions.InvokeWithConditionalDiscardedUndoScope(IUndoServices undoServices, Boolean condition, IWorkbook workbook, UndoableActionType actionType, Action action)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.Fill.PollingInitialFillSession.ResumeFill(Boolean onTimer)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.PollingFillManager.b__7(IFillSession fillSession)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.ClientShared.Model.QueriesUtilities.ForEachWithChangeScope[T](IEnumerable`1 items, Func`2 getQueries, Action`1 action)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.Fill.FillManager.ForEachFillSessionByWorkbook(Action`1 action)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.PollingFillManager.UpdateQueries()
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.PollingFillManager.b__6()
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.ExceptionHandlerExtensions.HandleExceptions(IExceptionHandler exceptionHandler, Action action)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.PollingFillManager.OnFillUpdateTimerTick(Object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Timer.OnTick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Timer.TimerNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

User ID:
f1b43d3f-ed65-4886-993e-0d6507a0de3f

Supports Premium Content:
True

Telemetry Enabled:
True

DPI Scale:
100%

Formulas:

section Section1;

shared #"DataRecords Campaign_000008" = let
    Źródło = PostgreSQL.Database("10.100.120.18", "ContactDirect"),
    DataRecords_Campaign_000008 = Źródło{[Schema="DataRecords",Item="Campaign_000008"]}[Data]
in
    DataRecords_Campaign_000008;

shared #"DataRecords Campaign_000008_ChangeLog" = let
    Źródło = PostgreSQL.Database("10.100.120.18", "ContactDirect"),
    DataRecords_Campaign_000008_ChangeLog = Źródło{[Schema="DataRecords",Item="Campaign_000008_ChangeLog"]}[Data]
in
    DataRecords_Campaign_000008_ChangeLog;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is: bug in npgsql 3.2.5 - after installing 3.1.9 - everything works gr8 ;)